Understanding wrong approach to "Probability of forming a triangle".
I am trying to answer the following question:
Given a stick and break it randomly at two places, what is the probability that you can form a triangle from the pieces? The two points on the stick will be selected randomly (uniformly along the length of the stick) and independently.
The task has already been solved here Probability of forming a triangle.
I tried a slightly different approach but am unfortunately, not able to identify my mistake. I suspect I might be conditioning wrong. Here is what I did:
Let L be the length of the stick. Suppose the first cut has length x and the second cut has length y. The remaining stick has length L - (x + y). Using the conditions to form a triangle I obtained:
$ x + y > L - (x + y) \iff x + y > \frac{1}{2}L $
$ L - (x + y) + y > x \iff \frac{1}{2}L > x $
$ L - (x + y) + x > y \iff \frac{1}{2}L > y $

Now the probability is the are described by the inequalities divided by the area of the $L\times L$ square yielding $\frac{1}{8}$, however the correct solution is $\frac{1}{4}$

In your approach, what is the distribution of $y$? If you start calculating areas of $L \times L$ you require that both $x$ and $y$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,L]$.

My bad, I edited the question to include the distribution.

The issue is that $y$ isn't actually uniformly distributed on $[0,L]$. But I've posted an answer now to this effect.

Following your approach, $x$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,L]$ and $y$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,L-x]$.
Note this is different to the approach of having $x$ and $y$ both distributed on $[0,L]$ and having stick lengths of e.g. $x$, $y-x$, $L-y$.
If you sketch your graph as before, the area is indeed $\frac{1}{8}$ however this should be as a fraction of the area $[0,L] \times [0,L-x]$ which is itself $\frac{1}{2}$.
The ratio of which gives you $\frac{1}{4}$ as required.

Thank you! Now I get it :)
